# Deploying .NET 3.5 framework on Win CE 6

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-ce

I need to install .net 3.5 compact framework on WINCE 6 device using wceload.exe command on startup.

Problem is, i have .net 3.5 cab file on my storage card and i have managed to install it, But, when i want to configure WinCe device to run it on startup after device reboot it wont work because there is not enough space on main partition.

If i remove /noui parameter it will ask me for location, I'll choose storage card and then it will work. With this parameter hes trying to install on default location where there is not enough space. I wonder is there any way to tell cab where to install himself ? I really need to do this without prompting me for location.

Ive also tried to install .net35 framework on storage card and after installation save registry. Without success again, after device reboot it wont work.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to rebuild the CAB file to specify a new install location.   VS2005+ can create CABs, although I'm not sure if it can edit/rebuild an existing one.   Editing INF files manually is painful at best.

We use [CE Cab Manager](http://www.ocpsoftware.com/products.php?nm=cecabmgr) to create and edit our CE based thinclient CAB files.   Its not free, but they have a trial and its inexpensive to purchase.   It was the only tool we could find that would let us do all the customization we needed.

Comment: He's talking about the CF itself, so I'm not sure that "rebuilding the CAB" is a very good option.

Comment: I got that, I was saying you could recreate the CF's CAB.   Yes its big, but a tool like CE Cab Manager wouldn't care.    Admittedly I've not tried this myself, just trying to make a suggestion.